# How to update a specific row and a specific column in a datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm trying to update a specific row and a specific column in a `datagridview`.

```vb
For x = 0 To Array.Length - 1
    Me.DataGridView4.Rows.Add(L_limit + x)
Next
```

The above code is updating the values in all rows in column 1, but the below code is not working.

```vb
For x = 0 To Array.Length - 1            
    DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = L_limit + x
Next
```

When I run this, I get the error: `Index was out of range`.

How do I update columns 2, 3, etc.? I tried a lot, but nothing is working.

Comment: When I run the second code I get the below error
"Index was out of range"

Comment: Have you checked if the column and row, you would like to set, are existing in datagridview?

Comment: Yes, I have this
DataGridView4.ColumnCount = 15

Comment: DataGridView4.ColumnCount = 15 ' columns to create 

        For x As Integer = 0 To Array.Length - 1
            DataGridView4(x, 0).Value = L_limit + x
        Next


    End Sub

When I run this code I get the below error "Index was out of range"

Comment: Sorry,I deleted my previous comment because I forgot, that you use VB.net. Is Array.Length= 15?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "the below code is not working" is not clear, but you can update given column in given row of datagridview in the following alternative ways:

// Modify the value in the first cell of the second row.
Me.DataGridView4.Rows[1].Cells[0].Value = "new value";

// The previous line is equivalent to the following line.
Me.DataGridView4.dataGridView4[0, 1].Value = "new value";

This is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following example to update first column in DataGridView:

```
Dim Array As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DataGridView4.Rows.Add(Array.Length)
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim L_limit As String = "L"
    For x = 0 To Array.Length - 1
        Me.DataGridView4(0, x).Value = L_limit + x.ToString 'Update column 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Result of my test:

[image]